# String comparison is too slow in R language

Tags: r, string, loops, comparison

there

String comparison is too slow in R language.
it will take 3 minutes, it is too slow; if the string is longer, it will take more time. Are there any ways to fast compare strings? Thanks!

```
    date()
    strArray1<-rep("1234567890",10000)
    strArray2<-rep("1234567890",10000)
    tt<-0
    for(xx in 1:10000)
    {
        for(yy in 1:10000)
        {
            if(strArray1[xx]==strArray2[yy])
            {
                tt<-tt+1
            }

        }

    }
    date()
```

**UPDATE:**
In fact, I have two files, say a.txt and b.txt as follows:

```
a.txt (>10000 lines):
abc00001
abc00035
abc15747
....
```

b.txt(>50000 lines):

```
abc00001 blablabla...
abc00002 blablabla...
abc00003 blablabla...
abc00004 blablabla...
....
abc60000  blablabla...
```

What I want to do is to extract rows from b.txt. The rows which contain a.txt's IDs are to be extracted. This will compare thousands of strings and take long time.

Comment: Is this a comment or a question?  I've never seen R, but from the looks of it you are trying to compare strings 10000x10000 times (100,000,000 comparisons).  That will be 'slow' in most programming languages.

Comment: Your nested for loops will be slow in every language that can do this

Comment: I do not agree with you. If use C or Perl , it probably use less than one minute. I had ever use C to process >100 million Strings, it was very fast.

Comment: Because you are doing it wrong. You need to vectorize your code. tt <- sum(strArray1 == strArray2 depending on what you are up to.

Answer (score 1):

String comparisons per se are not terribly slow:

```
> v <- rep("1234567890",100)
> microbenchmark(v=="1234567890")
Unit: nanoseconds
              expr min  lq    mean median  uq   max neval
 v == "1234567890"   0 355 1006.05    355 709 39639   100
```

The expression `v == "1234567890"` requires 100 string comparisons to evaluate. The mean time to do so is 1000 nanoseconds which implies that (on my machine) it takes an average of 10 nanoseconds for such a comparison. That is reasonably quick for strings of length 10. On the other hand `for` loops in R are notoriously slow. You need to find a way to vectorize the code (which will run the implicit loops in optimized C rather than interpreted R).

For example, the following vectorized code (which computes the same value of `tt` as your code) runs in less than 1 second:

```
print(date())
strArray1<-rep("1234567890",10000)
strArray2<-rep("1234567890",10000)
tt<-sum(sapply(strArray1,function(s){sum(strArray2 == s)}))
print(tt)
print(date())
```

Doubtless it could be improved even better since solutions which use `sapply` are frequently suboptimal.